# A question about projection operators

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I meet this question

Let $\left\{ {{P}_{\alpha }}:\alpha \in A \right\}$is a family of projection operators，Prove that there is a projection operator P such that $P\ge {{P}_{\alpha }}$ for all $\alpha \in A$, and that for any projection operator Q, when $Q\ge {{P}_{\alpha }}$ for all $\alpha \in A$, then $Q\ge P$.

I first try with two projection operators $P_1,P_2$, But I only proved that $P=P_1+P_2-P_1P_2$ is projection operator when $P_1,P_2$ is commutable. How should I think about this question？

Comment: Take $P$ to be the projection of the closed span of $\cup_{\alpha}M_{\alpha}$ where $M_{\alpha}$ is the range of $P_{\alpha}$.

Comment: Define projection operator. Are you working on the Hilbert space level?

Comment: @J.DeRo Yes, I'm learning functional analysis.

Comment: @geetha290krm Can you provide more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints: I will assume that you are dealing with orthogonal projections on a  Hilbert space.
$P\ge P_{\alpha}$ implies that $P_{\alpha}x=0$ whenever $Px=0$. Since the range of a projection is the  orthogonal complement of the kernel we get $M_{\alpha} \subseteq M$ where $M$ is the range of $P$. Converse is also true. So  $P\ge P_{\alpha}$ for each $\alpha$ iff $M$ contains $M_{\alpha}$ for each $\alpha$. Can you continue?